# How can I programmatically check if JFR is recording?

Tags: java, jfr

Java Flight Recorder provides simple APIs to detect if it's available ([`FlightRecorder.isAvailable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/FlightRecorder.html#isAvailable())) or initialized ([`FlightRecorder.isInitialized()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/jdk.jfr/jdk/jfr/FlightRecorder.html#isInitialized())). But there's no obvious API to detect if it's actually recording. Maybe I could check `FlightRecorder.getFlightRecorder().getRecordings().isEmpty()`, but I'm not sure it would be accurate. Is there an obvious API I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if a recording is running, you must iterate all recordings and check their state.

I added the initialization check to prevent JFR to initialize when FlightRecorder.getFlightRecorder() is called.

```
public static boolean isRunning() {
  if (!FlightRecorder.isInitialized()) {
    return false;
  }
  for (Recording r : FlightRecorder.getFlightRecorder().getRecordings()) {
    if (r.getState() == RecordingState.RUNNING) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you want to detect when a recording starts, you can use the FlightRecorderListener.

```
FlightRecorder.addListener(new FlightRecorderListener() {
  @Override
  public void recordingStateChanged(Recording recording) {
    if (recording.getState() == RecordingState.RUNNING) {
      ...
    }
  }
});
```